# Setting global action on cakephp 3.3.5

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a call to action button that opens a form for users to subscribe. I'm trying to have this form on the global header. The action subscribe() is in the App Controller but not sure how to call it from every single view.

I've tried a few things but haven't been able to make it work.

```
<?= $this->Form->create($subscription, ['controller' => 'App', 'action' => 'subscribe']) ?>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a named route.

**/config/routes.php**

```
    $routes->connect('/subscribe' , ['controller'=>'App', 'action'=>'subscribe'] , ['_name' => 'subscribe']);
```

in your view

```
<?= $this->Form->create('Subscripton', [url => ['_name' => 'subscribe']]); ?>
```

Comment: also there is no need to put the method in app controller. The url could point to any controller

Answer (score 0):

Made it work in case anyone is having the same problem.

```
<?= $this->Form->create('Subscripton', ['url'=>['controller'=>'App', 'action'=>'subscribe']]); ?>
```